# Wrong FAB position on Pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, floating-action-button

I am using a FAB beside an EditText...
On Lollipop, it works properly i.e. exactly beside EditText but on Pre-Lollipop, it shows quite attached and a bit on a lower side...

Here is the Screenshot -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QVtF.jpg

Here's the Code I'm using in a Fragment Layout -

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_id"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="95.0dip">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:textColorHint="#ffb7b7b7"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Username"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions">

            <requestFocus/>

        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/hit"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:rippleColor="#64B5F6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you have used fixed width `250dp` for `TextInputLayout` and `AutoCompleteTextView`. Also used `FloatingActionButton` fixed `left-margin` as `250dp`.

Here is the working `XML` code for showing `same layout` in all `Android` versions.

**Update your XML as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/hit"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:rippleColor="#64B5F6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:textColorHint="#ffb7b7b7"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Username"
            android:ems="10"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions">

            <requestFocus/>
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working XML file .. Try with  this XML ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/hit"   
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:rippleColor="#64B5F6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/til_id"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/til_id"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/til_id" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:textColorHint="#ffb7b7b7"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Username"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="trial"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions">

            <requestFocus/>

        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Hope this will work good ..